# Is there a way to call API not on client side?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, rest

Currently in my site, the API Call is in the client-side JavaScript meaning that anyone can spam refresh and use up the limited amount of API Calls (At least I assume that is how it works).

I am new and I want to know if I can call the API Locally and then push that data to the client end.

Here is the format of my API Calls:

```
const res = await fetch(`https://link.com`, {
        headers: {
            'X-RapidAPI-Host': "link",
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "key"
        }, 
    });
```

I am currently using simple JavaScript with jQuery. Node.js, AWS or some other services may be required for what I want but I am not sure, any help would be amazing. I have tried seeking answers to this question but was not able to find anything that made any sense.

Comment: what do you mean, call "locally"?

Comment: Im not too sure to be honest, I assume it means server side. You tell me, should an API Call be in the client side code? Wouldnt that make it so the user can spam the API Call by refreshing the page? I am new to all this!

Comment: @seanLawton can you provide some documentation or video so I can look into it?

Comment: Instead of calling the external API from js, create an endpoint in your own application (server-side) as a "proxy".  You can then check the IP address and apply whatever limits you see fit (eg throttle per time, limit per day) against that IP address.  It depends on what you mean by "limited mount of API calls" - I've assumed you have a third-party API that you're calling that charges if you go over a limit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a helpful article on caching API requests. This method is done client side and should be suitable for your question: https://dev.to/adancarrasco/caching-api-requests-in-javascript-mc4